# Typo3 9.5 / iFrame embed in RTE

Tags: iframe, typo3, rte

Is there anyway to embed an iFrame in the RTE in typo3 backend?
I want to embed google maps and not have to use an extension, so is there any way to do this?

I tried using

```
RTE.default {

    proc {
      allowTags := addToList(iframe,embed,script)

      allowTagsOutside := addToList(iframe,embed,script)

      entryHTMLparser_db.allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
    }

  }
```

in my Page.typoscript but unfortunately it didn't work.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the first answer, it is possible to use the `iframe` [CKEditor plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/iframe) which is shipped with TYPO3, in this way:

In your .yaml config (Just relevant parts):

```
editor:
    config:
        # add the toolbargroup if needed (e.g. default.yaml and full.yaml configurations already have it.)
        toolbarGroups:
            - { name: insert }
        extraPlugins:
            - iframe
processing:
    allowTags:
        - iframe
```

Then in your TypoScript Setup:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.allowTags :=addToList(iframe)
```

There is a downsize in this method that I was not able to circumvent so far: the `<iframe>` gets surrounded by a `<p>` tag in the CKEditor;

If you also add

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.externalBlocks:=addToList(iframe)
```

The `<iframe>` if no more surrounded by paragraphs, but a couple of empty paragraphs appear *before* the iframe

Comment: this config adds additional <p> before iframe every time I save the record

Answer (score 1):

I always use the HTML content element to add iframes. It works like expected and you don't need to arrange the RTE (which is not designed for putting iframes into it).

Comment: I don't have a HTML content element in my typo3 BE (using version 9.5). Are you talking about an extension?

Comment: No, it is a standard content element, in the "New content" wizard > tab "Special elements" > "Plain HTML". if you don't see it I think you have some page or user TSConfig that hides it :/ Third party extensions to embed a map are https://extensions.typo3.org/?L=0&id=1&tx_solr%5Bq%5D=map